# converting mp3 to wav using ffmpeg and pydub

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert mp3 file into wav using below code:

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment

# assign files
input_file = "recording.mp3"
output_file = "result.wav"

# convert mp3 file to wav file
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_file)
sound.export(output_file, format="wav")
```

This is the error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried converting the file with `ffmpeg` itself to see if it works? Because provided code works on random mp3 files.

Comment: Yes, I am running this `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.wav` and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

# convert wav to mp3
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', source_path,
                     destination_path])
```